# Kotlin extract information from JSON retrofit response and map them to Textview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

So the case is, I have a recyclerview `ProductListFragment.kt` that each item has click listener that will show a dialog pop up.Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWwcq.png). The dialog that contained the information of each item will be shown in the popup dialog like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFQ9I.png).

This is the adapter for the `ProductListFragment.kt` recyclerview:

**ProductListAdapter.kt**

```
class ProductListItemHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    private val productName: TextView = itemView.productName
    private val productPrice: TextView = itemView.productPrice
    private val productStockQuantity: TextView = itemView.productStockQuantity

    private val detailProductName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductName)
    private val detailProductPrice: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductPrice)
    private val detailProductLastUpdate: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductLastUpdate)
    private val detailProductStockQty: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductStockQty)

    fun bind(
        product: ProductListPOJODataClassesDataItem,
        clickListener: ProductListOnItemClickListener
    ) {

        //This is for showing the information in each recyclerview item

        productName.text = product.proName
        productPrice.text = product.proSaleprice.toString()
        productStockQuantity.text = product.stkAllqty.toString()


        //And these are for the detail popup dialog content

        detailProductName.text = product.proName
        detailProductPrice.text = product.proSaleprice.toString()
        detailProductLastUpdate.text = product.sktLastupdate
        detailProductStockQty.text = product.stkAllqty.toString()

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.onItemClicked(product)
        }
    }
}


class ProductListAdapter(
    private var productList: ProductListPOJODataClasses,
    private val itemClickListener: ProductListOnItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductListItemHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductListItemHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.product_list_item_layout, parent, false)

        return ProductListItemHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productList.data!!.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductListItemHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = productList.data?.get(position)
        if (product != null) {
            holder.bind(product, itemClickListener)
        }
    }
}


interface ProductListOnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClicked(product: ProductListPOJODataClassesDataItem)
}
```

As you can see from code above, both recyclerview item and the details dialog accessing the same JSON data class.

And this is the code snippet of `ProductListFragment.kt` itself

**ProductListFragment.kt**

```
   override fun onItemClicked(product: ProductListPOJODataClassesDataItem) {
         //Inflate the dialog with custom view
        val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from((activity as AppCompatActivity)).inflate(
            R.layout.product_list_dialog_layout, null
        )

        val selectedStkOutcode = product.stkOutcode
        val selectedProcode = product.stkProdcode

        if (selectedStkOutcode != null && selectedProcode != null) {

            // These line below show the information i desired in the log.

            Log.i("Product", "Clicked product name: ${product.proName}")
            Log.i("Product", "Clicked product price: ${product.proSaleprice}")
            Log.i("Product", "Clicked product stock qty: ${product.stkAllqty}")
            Log.i("Product", "Clicked product last update: ${product.sktLastupdate}")
        }

        //AlertDialogBuilder
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder((activity as AppCompatActivity))
            .setView(mDialogView)
            .setTitle("Product X")
        //show dialog
        val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()

        mDialogView.closeButton.setOnClickListener {
            //dismiss dialog
            mAlertDialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

As you can see, i mentioned that it shown the same informations I want in the LogCat. I want to do the same thing but in the dialog popup.
I think that both the recyclerview and the dialog popup for the details will be enough by using one adapter.

This is the Response from retrofit (The LogCat i mentioned above shows the same thing): 
[image]

I want to show all six variables in the dialog popup, But the problem is that it returns

> itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductName) must not be null

I know this can happen because `detailProductName` is not included in the recycler view. It is a textview from the popup dialog.

How can I show all the informations in the dialog popup ? If there's any detail I miss or you want to know, Just mention in the Comment.

**Edit:**
This is the detail dialog layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailProductName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="X"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailProductPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rp. XXXXX"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailProductStockQty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="XX "
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailProductLastUpdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="XX - XX - XXXX"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

And this is `product_list_item_layout.xml`

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/CardView"
    android:id="@+id/sampleProductCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Apple Pie"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:id="@+id/productName"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:text="Rp. "
                    android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:id="@+id/productPrice"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="Stock :"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:id="@+id/productStockQuantity"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is binding `dialog's` `view` to `recyclerview's` layout's `view` which does not exist so it is returning null. Please follow below instruction and try

Remove the following from `ProductListItemHolder`

```
    private val detailProductName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductName)
    private val detailProductPrice: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductPrice)
    private val detailProductLastUpdate: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductLastUpdate)
    private val detailProductStockQty: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductStockQty)

    detailProductName.text = product.proName
    detailProductPrice.text = product.proSaleprice.toString()
    detailProductLastUpdate.text = product.sktLastupdate
    detailProductStockQty.text = product.stkAllqty.toString()
```

Add below code inside `ProductListFragment`'s `onItemClicked()`

```
 val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from((this as AppCompatActivity)).inflate(
                R.layout.product_list_dialog_layout, null
        )
 val detailProductName: TextView = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductName)
 val detailProductPrice: TextView = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductPrice)
 val detailProductLastUpdate: TextView = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductLastUpdate)
 val detailProductStockQty: TextView = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.detailProductStockQty)

detailProductName.text = product.proName
detailProductPrice.text = product.proSaleprice.toString()
detailProductLastUpdate.text = product.sktLastupdate
detailProductStockQty.text = product.stkAllqty.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didn't show us `product_list_item_layout` and I'm sure that this layout doesn't contain any `detailProductName`. But you use this layout for displaying data at RV. So, what I can suggest you: you can show dialogue inside RV adapter and no need for creating interface for sending data from RV adapter to fragment. Then, alert dialog in general can be used for showing basic info. For this purpose I will suggest you to use `Dialog` like this:

```
val dialog = Dialog(context!!)
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.product_list_dialog_layout)
dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.detailProductName).text = "some text will be here"

Objects.requireNonNull<Window>(dialog.window).setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
dialog.show()
```

Good tutorial [here](https://mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/). On the other hand if you want to use AlertDialog you can use these tutorials: [1](https://medium.com/@suragch/creating-a-custom-alertdialog-bae919d2efa5) and [2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-custom-dialog-in-android). So in adapter you can function which will receive all data from clicked item and represent it at dialogue. Good Luck :)

Comment: as I can see your item layout doesn't contain id which you see at logcat :( you can try suggested solution above also